# jquery validation form doesnt work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a registration form with some field requirements in the form written in php and I'm trying to add a validation plugin to it, but the plugin doesn't work, I'm not getting any errors.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">

</script>                           

<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
$("#regForm").validate({
    rules: {
        brukernavn: {
            required: true,
            minlength:3,
            maxlength:10
        },
        passord: {
            required: true,
            minlength:3,
            maxlength:10
        },
        bekreft_pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength:3,
            maxlength:10
        },
        E_post: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        bekreft_epost {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        messages: {


        }
    }
});

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "Obligatorisk felt:"
});
 });
</script>

 <form id="regForm" method="post" action="">
<label for="brukernavn">Brukernavn</label><br>
<input type='text' id="brukernavn" name="brukernavn"><br>

<label for="passord">Passord</label>
<input type="password" id="passord" name="passord"><br>

<label for="bekreft_pass">Bekreft passord</label>
<input type="password" id="bekreft_pass" name="passord2"><br>

<label for="E_post">E-post</label>
<input type="E-post" id="E_post" name="E-post"><br>

<label for="bekreft_epost">Bekreft e-post</label>
<input type="E-post" id="bekreft_epost" name="E-post2"><br>
<br>

<input type='submit' id"submit" value='Register'>
```

Does anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: you havent closed the Input tag`s and even form tag, bad practice

Comment: the close tag for the form didnt seem to come with the code i posted, but it's there, and just tryed closing the input tags and the problem didnt seem to go away

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing colon character here: `bekreft_epost {` it should be `bekreft_epost: {`

Also, there is no closing form tag.

Comment: Im really new at this started a week ago learning php and jquery, but thank you, should've seen it myself tho.

Comment: Don't forget to mark a reply as the answer :)

Comment: And a tip: use the javascript console/debugger that come with most browsers. Usually its available by pressing F12.

Answer (score 1):

`messages` should not be under `rules`:

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/uGsXC/10/

Also, the validation rule names must match the field NAME attribute and not the ID:

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/uGsXC/12/